Time expressions yet again
"I will do it next month"
He said he would do it the next month or the following moth or the month later or after.
All of those are corrrect. We just have many options.
"I will do it next two months"
He said he would do it ......now what?
Do we change "next two months" and how?
Context: those sentences were said years ago. We don't remember time excatly.

"I will do it next two months" is not good English. What is it supposed to mean?

Same as before.  Report the time relative to the present time in which you are reporting.  Reported speech is not a grammar exercise.  There is no grammatic transformation that converts direct speech to reported

I don't consider "He said he would do it the month later" to be correct. A month later could mean 'four weeks after he said it'. If you mean 'during the following month', it has to be the month after.

@KateBunting  How would you report this "I will be doing next 3 months". He said he would be doing it what are the possibilities?

It's not clear what you intend it to mean. "I will be doing the next 3 months" could mean that they will be covering some job for the next quarter. In that case, and if it was said a long time ago - "He said he would be doing the next 3 months".

@KateBunting do we always need 'the". For instsance. "I will be staying here two weeks but the next two weeks"?

The is always required before next in this context.


We don't remember time exactly

So why do we care??  Serioiusly! There is no need to report that he said "next month" if we have forgotten when he said it.  So don't.
You would report the information that matters here, "He said he would do it."
In languages there are grammatical transformations  For example a present tense sentence can be transformed to a past tense  "I run" -> "I ran".  This is a grammatical transformation. But reported speech isn't a grammatical transformation.  You are just describing an event, it just happens that the event was someone speaking.  But when you describe an event you don't need to include everything. If you are saying "my daughter scored a goal" you don't need to include which foot she used, the name of the goalkeeper, the ripples in the net, and so on, if they don't matter. So leave out the unimportant stuff.
